# Wordpress: deleted page automatically restored

Tags: wordpress

I got this problem on my WordPress site. When I delete the page and also delete it in the trash permanently it automatically restored even though I didn't restore the page. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

hope your having a great day ,It seems your issues is a little unclear , Are you able to download your theme and debug it into a local development environment , instead of your live website , you can even try it on a free web-hosting service that offers you a subdomain so you don't break your website

Setting up  a local development environment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru3KjHP5vxw

Required

1.XammpLINK : https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

2.Wordpress LINK : https://wordpress.org/download/

Steps:

1. Download Xampp and wordpress
2. Install Xampp to C:\
3. Extract WordPress archive
4. Copy word press extracted folder to C:\xampp\htdocs
5. Go to localhost on browser
6. Click on phpmyAdmin on top right
7. Choose user authentication from the top tab
8. Select a new user
9. Make sure you select create a new database with this username
10. go to localhost/word press
11. Install db and start installing word press
12. create new credentials for word press admin panel
13. finish installation and login.

Possible fixes for your website

1. updating WordPress to latest version https://wordpress.org/download/
2. Plugin conflict with WordPress like a page builder for example Element or

try disabling each plugin one by one to understand which one causes the error by adding a new page if any of those plugins break the page editor
try to reinstall it but backup first .

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. Maybe it's in my plugins

Comment: What I did is, I deleted some pages and delete them permanently in the trash but when refresh it goes back to published pages.

Comment: No problem mate , i hope this helps as well may you try to change the page published that you want to delete as a draft so it wont  be published at least until figuring out the plugin causing the error.

Comment: The template I use is from webflow, I just convert it to WordPress. Maybe there's a problem with my conversion to WordPress.

Comment: Ohh , let me know if i could assist with anything else regarding wordpress , i am not really that familiar with webflow . good luck to you sir and good day to you aswell. ,   try converting you webflow theme to a zip file and upload it to the local development environment in wordpress maybe test it out there heres a link discussing how to do that from webflow https://university.webflow.com/lesson/code-export

Comment: I got a new problem mate, check it here. https://ryanllp.com/. I got problem in my mobile view in header section

Comment: <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E" data-lazy-src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Logo.png">

Comment: This code should be src="" but when I check it on the live site It appears that there's a data-lazy-src=""

Comment: You could either remove the logo directly from the customize section in the admin panel tab , but will leave your navigation bar without the logo so to you have to add the url yousrself